# Valgrind Invalid read size of 1

Tags: c, valgrind

For the life of me i cant work out why I am getting an `invalid read size of 1` for this code snippet, I'm pretty sure its got something to do with me abusing the `char *url pointer`...

```
char *extractURL(char request[])
{
char *space = malloc(sizeof(char *));
space = strchr(request, ' ')+1;
char *hostend = malloc(sizeof(char *));
hostend = strchr(request, '\r');
int length = hostend - space;
if (length > 0)
{
    printf("Mallocing %d bytes for url\n.", length+1);
    char *url = (char *)malloc((length+1)*sizeof(char));
    url = '\0';
    strncat(url, space, length);
    return url;
}
//else we have hit an error so return NULL
return NULL;    
}
```

The valgrind error I am getting is :

```
==4156== Invalid read of size 1

==4156==    at 0x4007518: strncat (mc_replace_strmem.c:206)

==4156==    by 0x8048D25: extractURL ()

==4156==    by 0x8048E59: processRequest ()

==4156==    by 0x8049881: main ()

==4156==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

Can someone 'point' me in the right direction?

Comment: You allocate memory for url, then set it to a null pointer.  (url = '\0';)  Did you mean, perhaps, to set url[0] = '\0'; ?

Comment: Do you perhaps just want to use strncpy?

Comment: You also have memory leaks with your first two `malloc` calls, which by the way are themselves completely bogus, why would you reserve `sizeof` the size of a `char` *pointer*? Your third `malloc` also shows signs of potential confusion: (1) don't cast the return of `malloc`, this only hides bugs (2) `sizeof(char)` is `1` by definition, the number you pass to `malloc` is the number of `char` you want to be allocated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here

```
char *url = malloc((length+1)*sizeof(char));
url = '\0';
strncat(url, space, length);
```

you immediately lose the malloced memory by setting `url` to `NULL`. Note that `'\0'` is 0, which is a null pointer constant. And then you try to `strncat` something to an invalid memory location.

You probably meant to set

```
*url = '\0';
```

there.

Comment: That then leads to strncat doing a conditional jump on an unintialized value though does it not?

Comment: Well, I would actually expect a segfault when calling `strncat(NULL,something,n)`, but valgrind might report that, if it prefers.